# Mesibo chat on-premise integration issue with TCP ports 80, 443 which are occupied by our APACHE server

Tags: chat, mesibo

firewall-settings section they have said that the ports 80 and 443 should be opened, but we have already installed the APACHE server on our Linux server and the ports 80 and 443 are occupied already by our APACHE server. So its a conflict situation. What should we do here?

Answer (score 0):

mesibo on-premise server will detect and use other ports. You can ignore port warnings.